# Grainy display around dialog boxes in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compiz

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Dell Inspiron 15. It was working fine and there was no issue with the display or the laptop. But today morning when I turned on the laptop from sleep mode, it started to show a **white grainy background** around the dialog boxes and the corner buttons (close, minimise, and maximise buttons) are not visible. I can see some sort of change in the grain pattern in the position of the buttons when I place the mouse over the buttons. The buttons are working though.

Here is a screenshot,

[image: screenshot of the issue]

The display around it is fine, as you can see.

Update:

Similar issue was noted in Ubuntu 18.04 in the same laptop. The same grainy details can be seen around the time that is displayed on the lock screen. But it was not a big deal, as it just disappears in a second or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a partial fix to this problem. Run this code from the command line

```
setsid compiz --replace
```

However, I have to run this code everytime this issue comes up. I had tried to include this script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: This question was answered in ask ubuntu.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/896768/grainy-background-around-dialog-box

Comment: Also see this answer

http://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode